# Enforce browser rendering of "exact" font sizes?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following bit of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <span style = "font-size: 0.5in;">1/2"</span>
        <br>
        <span style = "font-size: 1in;">1"</span>
        <br>
        <span style = "font-size: 2in;">2"</span>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

On a desktop machine, this seems to render close enough to the requested size. But on all of the mobile browsers I've tried (Firefox, Chrome, Opera), it's much smaller (around 25% of the size specified). Why is that? I figured that an inch should be a fairly unambiguous measurement, but apparently not! Is there any way around it? And just to be clear, I do realize that absolute font sizes are not generally recommended, I'm just trying to find a way to achieve this for future reference.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I think I've found the solution. Putting this meta-tag in the  element seems to work (most of the time, anyway - Opera still ignores the request):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I was mistaken, this doesn't exactly work as expected. The fonts are definitely larger, roughly 50% of the requested size, but I would still prefer if they were a little closer to 100%. So, still an open question. I'll keep researching this myself, but any input would be appreciated.

By the way, a better meta tag than the above might be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
```

As it doesn't really make sense to prevent users from zooming their text...

Comment: Have a look at meta viewport tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is the Bootstrap viewport, could be better than a `scalable=no`

Comment: Yes, I agree. The post has since been amended with a similar alternative.

Answer (score 0):

An inch in CSS is always 96 pixels (*). As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) puts it,

> The unit `in` doesn't represent a physical inch on screen, but represents `96px`. That means that whatever is the real screen pixel density, it is assumed to be `96dpi`.

So if you happen to have a 96 DPI monitor, one inch comes out as one inch on the monitor. However, if you have a 120 DPI monitor, the result is smaller.

That's how it is.

Mobile devices seem to have smaller pixels on average, so on many mobile devices, the result would be even smaller. For example, a Samsung Galaxy 6S has 144 DPI (*), which would make a CSS inch as small as 2/3 of a real inch.

The good news is that according to the same [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) page, Firefox has a unit called `mozmm` which is one physical millimeter. So then `<span style = "font-size: 12.7mozmm;">1/2"</span>` would do exactly what you want.
You can guess the bad news though.

(*) Now most mobile devices have multiple hardware dots per logical pixel, but don't let that confuse you. A pixel is not a hardware dot, simple as that. And the Samsung mentioned would have 577 dots per inch, but we don't use dots in CSS, OK?

Comment: I see! Then it just isn't possible to create a truly absolute-sized font. Bizarre. Well, I guess we just have to accept that. Thanks for the answer (marked as useful, but not enough rep's to count). Also found [this](http://static.zealous-studios.co.uk/projects/web_tests/PPI%20tests.html) to be pretty informative.

Comment: Well, if you're desperate, Firefox has a unit `mozmm` which does what you want - it is a physical unit rather than a number of pixels. See my edit.